# Is it possible to find and delete anything between two specified characters in an excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to clean up email addresses with "+" to get a clean list of actual email addresses. Here are a few examples-

richard.james+1000@gmail.com

richardbluth+peace@gmail.com

richardbutt+fakeemail@gmail.com

What I'm trying to do is to find a formula that can delete all characters between a "+" and "@", including the "+".

The output I'm expecting from the three example emails above is this:

richard.james@gmail.com

richardbluth@gmail.com

richardbutt@gmail.com

So far, the only way that I thought of is by doing text-to-columns by the "+" first, then once I pull apart the first part of the email, then I do another text-to-columns for the last part by "@" and then delete the middle characters between the "+" and the "@". Then I concatenate the first part of email with the last part.

So example-

richardbutt+fakeemail@gmail.com

1st text-to-columns splits "richardbutt" and "fakeemail@gmail.com"

2nd text-to-columns splits "fakeemail" and "gmail.com"

Lastly I just concatenate "richardbutt" with "gmail.com" and add the "@"

But I'm wondering if there is a way to do all of this within a formula? Would love to learn a new way from how I'm doing it currently.

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: If the answer below was correct, please mark it as so by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Thanks Scott, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
=MID(A8,1,FIND("+",A8)-1)&MID(A8,FIND("@",A8),LEN(A8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate, you can do this with a Find and Replace.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Find and Replace dialog box.  In the "Find what" type in `+*@` and in the "Replace with" type in `@` and click "Replace All"

[image: Find and Replace example]